# Find a formula for the $n$-th power, given $x^3=-ax$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given the relation $$x^3=-ax$$, $x$,$a$ are real numbers.

Find the $x^n$

My attempt, by trying some values I get $$x^4=-ax^2$$
$$x^5=a^2x$$
$$x^6=a^2x^2$$
$$x^7=-a^3x$$
$$x^8=-a^3x^2$$
and so on

So I can see that $x^n$ looks like $$a^{\frac{n}{2}-1} x^2$$ for $n$ even
and $$a^{\frac{n-1}{2} }x$$ for $n$ odd.

However, this is not the answer since I can see that for each case, the sign alternates, but I can't seem to write a function that alternates sign every step.

In general, I know that $(-1)^n$ does exactly this, however, here I have only odd numbers in one case and only even numbers in the other, so for example, $$x^n=(-1)^n a^{\frac{n}{2}-1} x^2$$ for $n$ even, would not alternate sign.

I want to ask, what function would do that?

Answer (score 2):

The right-hand side of your final answer should not contain $x$.

A brute-force hint.

- If $x=0$, then $x^n=0$ for any positive integer $n$.
- If $a=0$, then you must have $x=0$.
- If $a>0$, and $x\ne 0$, then $x^2=-a$, which is impossible.
- If $a<0$, and $x\ne 0$, then $x^2=-a$, and $x=\pm\sqrt{-a}$.

---

Alternatively, consider the equivalent equation $x^3+ax=0$, which can be written as $x(x^2+a)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3 + ax = 0$$
$$x(x^2+a) = 0$$

If $a\ge 0$ then $x=0,\quad x^n=0.$

If $a<0$, then $x=0$ or $x\in \{(-a)^{1/2}, -(-a)^{1/2}\}, \quad x^n \in \{(-a)^{n/2}, (-1)^n(-a)^{n/2}\}$.

Thanks to @JoshuaWang for correcting my algebra!

Comment: $x^{3} + ax = x(x^{2} + a)$?

Comment: Ah!  you are right!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $ a=0$ then $ x=x^n=0$.

if $ x=0 $ then $ x^n=0$

If $ x\ne 0 $ then $ x^2=-a$ and

necessarily, $  a<0 $ or $ a=-b $ with $ b>0$.

So, $ x^2=b $ and $ |x|=b^{\frac 12}$

Thus

$$x>0\implies x^n=b^{\frac n2}$$

and
$$x<0\implies x^n=(-1)^nb^{\frac n2}$$